# Android Studio problema con el emulador Nexus 5x Api 25

Tags: android-studio

Necesito ayuda con android studio, cuando inicia el nexus 5x api25 me aparece una advertencia

> pixel launcher sigue sin funcionar

y da la opcion de cerrar la app.

revise si tiene lo necesario y se ve bien soy novato en esto de la programada y tengo un millon de dudas, pero estoy muy interesado en aprender.
¿Qué necesito?

Answer (score 1):

En este caso este es el mensaje que se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para resolver este problema edita las propiedades de tu AVD y configura que los gráficos sean emulados por software:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]